# How to convert string to json dictionary.?

Tags: swift, nsstring

Below piece of code, I am using to convert a `string` into a `dictionary`, but not working.

```swift
let body = "{status:0}"
do {
    let dictionary = try convertToDictionary(from: body ?? "")
    print(dictionary) // prints: ["City": "Paris"]
} catch {
    print(error)
}

func convertToDictionary(from text: String) throws -> [String: String] {
    guard let data = text.data(using: .utf8) else { return [:] }

    let anyResult: Any = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])

    return anyResult as? [String: String] ?? [:]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the input string isn't json I suggest a non-json solution

```
let array = body.dropFirst().dropLast().split(separator: ":").map {String($0)} 

var dictionary = [String: String]()
if let key = array.first, let value = array.last { 
    dictionary[key] = value
}
```

Comment: Work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. The value is `Int` so the type cast to `[String:String]` fails.
2. The JSON format requires keys wrapped in double quotes.

This works with `any` value type

```
let body = """
{"status":0}
"""

do {
    let dictionary = try convertToDictionary(from: body)
    print(dictionary) // prints: ["City": "Paris"]
} catch {
    print(error)
}

func convertToDictionary(from text: String) throws -> [String: Any] {
    let data = Data(text.utf8)
    return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any] ?? [:]
}
```

Comment: No string key for value in object around character 1. get this error.

Comment: this is my string "{"status":0}". do i need to place slash this "{\"status\":0}". i am getting plain string. It working fine for  "{\"status\":0}"

Comment: I recommend to use the multiline literal syntax which avoids the backslashes. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use `Codable` protocol. Instead of using dictionaries use some specific class/structure to parse data into. You can use code similar to this:

```swift
struct Status: Codable {
    let status: Int
}

let body = "{\"status\":0}".data(using: .utf8)!
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let status = try decoder.decode(Status.self, from: body)
    print(status) //Status(status: 0)
} catch {
    print("\(error)")
}
```

It is a more safe way to handle JSON response. Also, it gave you information about what goes wrong, so you can easily fix it. For example, if you use `let status: String` you will get this error:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.String, 
Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "status", intValue: nil)], 
debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a number instead.", 
underlyingError: nil))
```

---

More about `Codable` you can read in [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) article written by Apple, or search for `Codable` tutorial online - there are a lot of good articles about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
let body = "{\"status\":\"0\"}" 

do {
     let dictionary = try convertToDictionary(from: body )
      print(dictionary) 
   } catch {
        print(error)
  }

func convertToDictionary(from text: String) throws -> [String: Any] {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try (JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] ?? [:])
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }

    return [:]
}
```

Out Put -> ["status": 0]